# After "grub>" mensage install Fedora 20

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub

After installing the Fedora 20 sucessfully and rebooted, I have received the message on boot:

> Grub>

I stay stuck on this screen and don't know what to do. I think it might be a problem to load the grub2, that is created by fedora installer. But I don't know what to do to repair the grub2 in fedora - I used boot-repair on debian based distros to help me through this.

### More information:

I am installing side by side with Windows 8
I have tried to install creating partition automatically by installer
and also manual creating:

- ext4, / - 50gb
- swap (2 * sizeOf(RAM))
- ext2 /boot - 300mb
- biosgrub - 10mb

Could anyone help me what I am doing wrong to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall grub2 as explained on [askfedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/40578/how-to-reinstall-or-fix-grub-in-fedora-20/?answer=40593#post-id-40593).

You can also try [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/419013/267708).